# How to stop angular material's mdInput from changing color without being told to

Tags: angular, angular-material

Using @angular/material 2.0.0-beta3, if you have a form like this:

```
<div style="padding: 7px">

  <form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <md-input-container color="primary">
      <input mdInput type="text" formControlName="one" placeholder="one">
    </md-input-container> 
    <br/>
    <md-input-container color="primary">
      <input mdInput type="text" formControlName="two" placeholder="two">
    </md-input-container> 
  </form>
</div>
```

And a component like this:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http'
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'material-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

  private version: any;
  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(http: Http, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    // Display the currently used Material 2 version.
    this.version = http
      .get('https://api.github.com/repos/angular/material2-builds/commits/HEAD')
      .map(res => res.json())
  }

  ngOnInit():void{
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      one: ['', [Validators.required]],
      two: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });
  }

  submit():{

  }

}
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ie2k3OIdvAl64MqKa4hp)

It will start ignoring your 'color' choice and start coloring the field based on the associated form state as soon as you dirty the field.

I don't want my input fields to turn to the warning color until the user has tried to submit the form, but that isn't an option.  Previosuly I could tell it when I wanted it to change color based on a submit flag along with checking if the input is valid.  Now it seems the 'color' option just sets the initial color (and not even that - it is the initial color when the user enters the input field - so you get to enjoy your color choice for all of about 1 second).

Is there anyway to control the color of mdInput even after the user starts interacting with the field?

In the past, this would work, and the property to use was dividerColor (assuming you had a `submitted` property that you set to `true` when the form was submitted):

```
<md-input-container dividerColor="{{!submitted || myForm.valid ? 'primary' : 'warn'}}">
    <input mdInput    type="text" formControlName="one" placeholder="one">
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: Could you please provide more code. Very hard to test and debug without a working version. I have created a working online version **[here](https://plnkr.co/edit/xSU5QWqKsDUE2tURr9FQ?p=preview)** with your provided code, although please fork it with all of your code so that I can debug.

Comment: OK - done.  I have specified the `color` as `primary` (which is blue here I guess).  When the page loads, it is grey (not primary), then the user clicks in the field and it is primary, but as soon as the user clicks out of the field it changes to `warn` because the field is required - but I don't want to change the field color to warn the user until the user actually submits the field.  In prior versions of material I could do this using `dividerColor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a quick look through the documentation and, unfortunately, found no `Angular Material` way around this.

So instead, I went for the best universal approach and used direct CSS.

**1.** Here are the style rules to apply to your site. Not sure if you're using SASS or LESS or another CSS pre-processor, so here is the vanilla CSS:

```
.form-unsubmitted .mat-input-invalid.mat-focused .mat-input-placeholder {
  color: #3f51b5;
}

.form-unsubmitted .mat-input-invalid .mat-input-placeholder {
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.38);
}

.form-unsubmitted .mat-input-underline {
  border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}

.form-unsubmitted .mat-input-invalid.mat-input-invalid .mat-input-ripple {
  background-color: #3f51b5; 
}
```

**2.** Then, you need to add a class `form-unsubmitted` to your form element via `ngClass`:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="submit()" [ngClass]="{'form-unsubmitted': !submitted}">
    ...
</form>
```

**3.** And on `submit()` change the public variable to `true`, like so:

```
public submitted: boolean = false;

submit() {
   this.submitted = true;
}
```

**[Here is a working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/hBuu6VIfsnOfbYNLg70p?p=preview)**. All of the styles are in the head of the `index.html`.

Comment: Does the job.  I'm disappointed that the material team made the decision to have it work like it works though - seems pointless to even offer the ability to control the colour at all.

Comment: @WillyC yes I completely agree. I have moved from Angular Material to Materialize as I do not agree with a few of the choices that the AM team have made. Materialize has a far better community, tons more components, and there is a great Angular2 module for it.